# Artifact removed when entering next stage in pipeline

Tags: bash, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am creating pipeline in GitLab CI and at the moment everything works fine except one thing and that is when I save txt file in previous stage to artifact it is removed in next stage.

This is job 1:

```yaml
prep for build (other branches):
  stage: Fetching tags
  image: alpine
  allow_failure: true
  script:
    - apk add git
    - git --version
    - LATEST_TAG=$(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags)
    - echo $LATEST_TAG > tags.txt
    - echo "Latest tag from other branches is:"
    - cat tags.txt
  only:
    refs:
      - master
      - /^(([0-9]+)\.)?([0-9]+)\.x/
      - rc
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - tags.txt
    expire_in: 4 week
  tags:
    - auth
    - dev
    - docker
```

And this is job 2 that uses artifact from job 1:

```yaml
execution (other branches):
  stage: Build and Push Image
  dependencies:
    - prep for build (other branches)
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - LATEST_TAG=cat tags.txt
    - echo "Latest tag is $LATEST_TAG"
    - echo "{\"auths\":{\"$HARBOR_REGISTRY\":{\"username\":\"$HARBOR_USER\",\"password\":\"$HARBOR_PASSWORD\"}}}" > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
    - /kaniko/executor --cache=true --context $CI_PROJECT_DIR --dockerfile $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile --destination $HARBOR_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$LATEST_TAG
  only:
    refs:
      - master
      - /^(([0-9]+)\.)?([0-9]+)\.x/
      - rc
  tags:
    - auth
    - dev
    - docker
```

These are logs from job 2:

```sh
Checking out 21a67bd3 as master...
Removing CHANGELOG.md
Removing coverage-report/
Removing coverletReport/
Removing tags.txt
Skipping Git submodules setup
Downloading artifacts
00:01
Downloading artifacts for prep for build (other branches) (50868)...
Downloading artifacts from coordinator... ok        id=50868 responseStatus=200 OK token=sADMXgpX
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
.....

LATEST_TAG=cat tags.txt
/busybox/sh: eval: line 109: tags.txt: not found
Cleaning up file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 127
```

Any idea why this is happening ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The artifact is downloaded fine, the problem is the way you're setting the variable `LATEST_TAG`. It appears you're trying to set it to the result of the operation `cat tags.txt` but instead you're setting it to the string `cat`. The next part of the line  `tags.txt` is interpreted as another command, so it says  `tags.txt not found` because it cannot evaluate  `tags.txt` as a command.

Change that line to `LATEST_TAG=$(cat tags.txt)` to set `LATEST_TAG` to the result of `cat tags.txt`.

See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147420/what-is-in-a-command) for more on `$(command)`

Comment: Hi Adam ! 

Thank you for your response. I understood now what the problem was and I was able to solve it as you stated to me. Now everything is working properly.

Once again, thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Glad I could help solve the problem. If you don’t mind, could you accept my answer so others with similar questions can see there is an answer?

Comment: I accepted your answer, sorry I have not done that earlier I didn't know for that step. Again, thank you for helping me ! :)